# Python variable references

Tags: python, data-structures

New to Python and picking up some practice on DSA problems though I have previously only worked in Java. Why does option 2 work and option 1 does not? I have seen Python passes by object reference and suspect the answer is to do with using references of references.

Option 1

```
# Definition for singly-linked list.
# class ListNode:
#     def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.next = next

class Solution:
    def middleNode(self, head: Optional[ListNode]) -> Optional[ListNode]:
        current = head
        fastp = current
        slowp = current

        while (current and current.next):
            fastp = fastp.next.next
            slowp = slowp.next
            current = current.next                 
        return slowp
```

Option 2

```
# Definition for singly-linked list.
# class ListNode:
#     def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.next = next

class Solution:
    def middleNode(self, head: Optional[ListNode]) -> Optional[ListNode]:
        fastp = head
        slowp = head

        while (fastp and fastp.next):
            fastp = fastp.next.next
            slowp = slowp.next                    
        return slowp
```

Shown 2 example solutions above, one working and one incorrect but unsure why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In option 1, `current` is a reference that does not change in the loop.

Actually, it is not clear which line of the loop (assignment to `fastp` or assignment to `slowp`) was expected to change `current`.
Maybe something else was meant, and option 1 is just buggy?

Comment: sorry edited as I recreated the buggy solution from memory after finding the working option

Comment: @Siggyweb Now `current` walks as `slowp`, so Option 1 terminates as soon as `slowp` reaches the end. Whereas Option 2 terminates when `fastp` reaches the end.

Comment: Ah I see this makes sense, so option one is throwing a "NoneType' object has no attribute" error because fastp is advancing out of the list and into null list territory. Thank you!